# ¿Cómo designar permisos de usuario a mi aplicación de Windows form desde SQL con vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, permisos, users-roles, cuenta-usuario

Estoy realizando una aplicación de Windows Forms con VB.NET. Para entrar a la aplicación cada usuario debe tener un usuario, contraseña y rol.

La cuestión es que por cada rol necesito dar accesos diferentes a cada usuario.
Por ejemplo:

1. Administrador: Acceso total a todos los botones
2. Auxiliar: BotonEliminar.enable = false, BotonRegistrar.enable = True
3. Usuario: Solo puede ver información mas no podrá hacer cambios.

Pero el problema es que habrán usuarios que en algún momento tendrán algunos privilegios extras y para hacer esto toca estar modificando el código de mi aplicación.

Lo que quiero es dar esos permisos directamente de una tabla de SQL, es decir que cuando el usuario se loguee traiga los permisos desde mi base de datos SQL y no sea directamente desde mi código.

Espero me hayan entendido, agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: PEro, cual es el problema?

Comment: El problema consiste en que no quiero dar privilegios desde mi código de VB.NET sino hacerlo desde una base de datos en SQL.

Comment: gbianchi, Gracias por tu respuesta.

Lo que estoy buscando es que en el evento Load de mi form se carguen todos los permisos o accesos a los controles de mi aplicación desde una base de datos.

No lo quiero hacer directamente desde mi aplicación porque no seria dinámico.
Quiero que por ejemplo; si el usuario de tipo AUXILIAR tiene el `BotonEliminar.enabled=False` yo quiero que mas adelante desde mi base de datos yo le pueda cambiar ese privilegio a `BotonEliminar.enabled=True` sin necesidad de estar tocando el código de mi aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías crear una clase (puedes usar un form con diferentes *checkbox* por ejemplo) para configurar los permisos de usuario (si esta chequeado, esta habilitado).
Guardas en la BDD los `values` de esos `checkbox`.
Una alternativa sería guardarlos en 1 solo campo de una tabla como un array, por si luego agregas botones o funcionalidades, no deberás modificar la estructura de la BDD.
Asignas todo a `enabled = false`
Al iniciar la aplicación, cargas la clase y la rellenas con los datos almacenados en la BDD correspondientes a ese usuario.
Cuando toque instanciar cada formulario, chequeas en la clase los permisos que cargó el sistema al logear el usuario y asignas como `enabled=true` los que son habilitados para ese usuario.

Al formulario para asignar permisos podría ser algo así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos checkBox los validas y los guardas en la BDD (guardas el value, es decir `true` o `false`)

Cuando el usuario logea, lees la base de datos con algo similar a esto `SELECT * FROM permisos WHERE nivel = 'Auxiliar'` y asignas sus permisos a una clase con un `reader`

```
            consulta = "SELECT * from permisos where nivel = 'Auxiliar'"
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(consulta, con)
            Dim usr As New nivelDeUsuario 'el nombre de tu clase
            Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While myReader.Read()
                usr.isadmin = myReader("admin")
                usr.modAdmin = myReader("modadm")
                usr.parame = myReader("param")
                usr.btnElim = myReader("botEliminar")
                'y así para llenar todos las variables que necesites
            End While
```

Luego, en cada `form` que abras, chequeas los valores de esas variables. Y pones algo como `BotonEliminar.enabled = usr.btnElim`

> Será true o false según tengas almacenado en la BDD y hayas recuperado
> para asignar a la clase.

Comment: Hola Gracias por tu respuesta. Tienes algún ejemplo al respecto de como debería hacerlo, así sea algo sencillo...

Comment: @JamesJhairToroCantero A ver si edito y te hago algo rapido como para que te des una idea.

Comment: @JamesJhairToroCantero ya pude editar y poner algo de código para que te orientes, por supuesto no es exactamente lo que necesitas, porque no vimos nada de tu código, pero a modo orientación puede serte de utilidad.

Comment: Hice los conectores con MySQL y acabo de ver que tu usas SQL, pero es similar el código, solo que con los conectores de SQL